# Microsoft Office files get stuck on 'Processing' when opening, when within the OneDrive folder

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, onedrive

I’ve just received a new laptop for work and am having issues with opening Word, Excel, etc. items that are within the OneDrive directory.

They get stuck on this 'Processing' screen when loading a file that resides within the OneDrive folder:

[image]
[image]

I can open documents that are not within the OneDrive folder without any issue.

The issue is described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_o365b/microsoft-office-apps-stuck-in-processing-crashes/f915263f-9908-4966-8bbb-8b34bd736a07) and I have run ‘**%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset**’ as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reset-onedrive-34701e00-bf7b-42db-b960-84905399050c#:%7E:text=1%20Open%20a%20Run%20dialog%20by%20pressing%20Windows,on%20the%20OneDrive%20desktop%20app.%20Learn%20more%20on...support.microsoft.com).

This fix didn’t work, so I:

- Copied all of my files to a safe location
- Uninstalled OneDrive
- Deleted all the items under the OneDrive directory
- Renamed ‘C:\Users\parichar\AppData\Local\OneDrive’ to ‘C:\Users\parichar\AppData\Local\OneDrive-Old’
- Restarted my PC
- Re-installed OneDrive

This didn't resolve the issue.

I then:

- Ran a full online repair on Office (followed by a reboot)
  This also didn't resolve the issue

I then disabled Office File Collaboration as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-office-applications-to-sync-office-files-that-i-open-8a409b0c-ebe1-4bfa-a08e-998389a9d823?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us). This did resolve the issue, but I would prefer to have this functionality enabled.

How can I resolve the Office/OneDrive issue, whilst having Office File Collaboration enabled?

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the issue:

**Renamed:**

%localappdata%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\

**To:**

%localappdata%\Microsoft\Office\16.0-old